# What are the differences in the following sentences

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases, phrase-choice

> - I will go on on Monday too
> - I will go on Monday as well

Do they have same meaning ?

If not what are the differences between them ?

Comment: Also *I will go on on Monday **also***.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing. "As well" might be slightly more formal than "too", and you will often hear the informal "me too".

Context is important, as they could both either mean that you are going on Monday *as well as on another day* (ie you are going twice), or that you are going on Monday *as well as somebody else who is going that day*.

You can also use "also", but that is usually placed before the verb or adjective, rather than at the end of the sentence:

> I will also go on Monday